# How to minimize the Command prompt condition based when it is executing the bat file?

Tags: cmd

I know how to start bat file with minimized window using other bat file.

Example:

```
first.bat 
start /min second.bat

second.bat
@echo i'm minimized
```

But in my code base, run only one bat with minimized window. i'm using

```
 start /min cmd /C "%~dpnx0"
```

this one, but it starts again my bat file. Please help me.Thanks in advance

Comment: I got here because ChatGPT offered me to add 'start /b cmd /c "%~dpnx0"' in the beginning of my script to prevent the terminal popup.  It looped till it almost crushed my computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to have a batch file launch itself in a minimized fashion. However, you'll need some way of telling the recursive invocation that it doesn't need to recurse again.

If your script doesn't already use command-line arguments, you could use one:

```
@echo off
rem blah blah blah
if "%1" == "/minimized" (goto min)
start /min "%~f0" /minimized
exit
:min
rem actual code goes here
```

If it does already use arguments, you could set an environment variable:

```
@echo off
rem blah blah blah
if defined MYSCRIPT_MINIMIZED (goto min)
set MYSCRIPT_MINIMIZED=yes
start /min "%~f0"
exit
:min
rem actual code goes here
```

Doubtless there are other techniques - those are the ones I could think of right now.